# connect Windows 7 to internet using Linksys with ethernet cable

Tags: windows-7, windows, router, networking

I have a Linksys router and I want to connect my PC to internet with it. how can I do this?

Comment: It depends on the model of router. If you provide that information, we may be able to help.  Meanwhile, you could try the Linksys support page at http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-ca/wireless/linksys/.

Comment: Do you have a modem?

Comment: Is it just me, or does this sound kind of like http://superuser.com/questions/123704/the-site-is-down-closed?

Comment: Do you have an internet connection from an ISP? What type of connection? Do you have a static IP? Is the modem set to routed or bridged (if there is a modem)? What model of router do you have? What functions do you want the router to perform for you? We need a lot more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a modem if your ISP provides the internet connection via a phone line. If your ISP provides the internet connection via a LAN cable, you don't need a modem.

Here's the example steps for you to connect your devices:

First connect your phone line to the modem, and then connect your router to the modem, and last connect your PC to the router. If you connect the internet via a LAN cable, you can bypass the modem and connect the router directly to the LAN port which is provided by your ISP. After all devices connected, power all up and use the browser on your PC to login to your router to setup an internet connection setting for the first time.

For example, open http://192.168.1.1 to open the router configuration page, enter the default user name and password when prompted and then setup a PPPoE connection. You should refer to your router manual to find the exact IP address and default user/password combination. Here is a list of some default user names and passwords, just FYI:

Default user names:

```
Linksys BEFW11S4, WRT54G: admin
Linksys EtherFast Cable/DSL Ethernet routers: Administrator
Linksys Comcast routers: comcast
All other Linksys routers: [none]
```

Default passwords:

```
Linksys BEFW11S4: [none]
Linksys Comcast routers: 1234
All other Linksys routers: admin
```

Comment: You are assuming that he will be using PPPOE, also that he will be using DSL specifically. This process will be different depending on the ISP. He could have a bridged modem and need to statically set his IP, he could have cable and need to setup DHCP on the router, he could have fiber and need to configure multiple IPs. He could have EoC and require a crossover cable and special duplex settings. There are so many possibilities.

Comment: Yes, I was just telling him the steps to setup a PPPoE connection. But since he can't tell his connection type and which ISP he's using, all we can help him are based on assuming. If he connects via a cable, the modem is not required. I'll make a little correction to my answer immediately.

Comment: @Miller If he is connecting to a Cable internet provider, a modem is still required. A modem is always required.

Comment: @sidran32, a modem is only required for adsl, adsl2+, vdsl and cable, but there are a number of other types of connections that do not use modems (sdsl, idsl, fiber, eoc, t1).

Comment: @MaQleod Then for those connections, wouldn't you still require an intermediary between the router and the incoming signal? Granted my experience has not been with any of those, personally, but I am skeptical that they output via an ethernet jack. Also, I am skeptical that someone who would ask this question would be getting a T1 line. And as far as I know, EOC is long outdated.

Comment: @sidran32, EoC is very new and a growing market. sdsl and idsl are very outdated. EoC uses a type of bridge, similar to a modem, but with a lot more control. What it does is bond multiple connections together (whether bdsl or proprietary). idsl and t1 use a router to change from frame relay to ethernet - these are special routers that usually need to be able to keep timing, sdsl is more closely related to adsl (atm), but uses a router instead of a modem. Fiber usually goes through a fiber to copper change somewhere between the F1 and the prem and then requires a specialized router.

Comment: @MaQleod I thought EoC was the precursor to modern ethernet. Back in the day, they used to use coax cables to run networks through buildings and tap in the middle of them to get a hookup at any particular area down the length of the cable. Maybe I'm thinking of something else. And for those other cases, if they require specialized routers, my guess is that it is unlikely that he would be able to use his Linksys router to connect to the Internet. :P

Comment: @sidtran32, not sure what that is through coax, I just know what the ISPs I have worked for or worked with call EoC. It isn't uncommon to use a secondary router after those other types of routers. In my experience it is actually quite common (usually the ISP controls those routers so end users will setup their own on one IP in the block they are handed and NAT on their own so they can control port forwarding and DHCP pool handouts themselves).

Answer (score 0):

You will need a modem, and not just a router, to connect to the Internet.

If you don't have a modem, you'll have to sign up for Internet service and get one. A router will simply allow multiple computers to connect through one Internet connection.

You will have to consult with whatever ISP you sign up with on how to set up your router for their network. Most routers have similar settings, and most new routers make setup relatively simple. If you bought your Linksys router recently, it likely will have a setup CD with a wizard that will guide you through the setup process. However, all of this presumes that you already purchased an Internet subscription and received a modem in the mail.

The one thing to keep in mind is that most ISPs will send you a modem/router combination device by default, but when you sign up you should be able to say that you want just a modem (I prefer doing this myself). If you get just the modem, you will be able to use the router you have already.

This all depends on the ISP you go with. So, start there. If you have an ISP (or after you sign up with one), you may come back on here with more information and we may be able to give more specific advice.